# Can not use telnet localhost

Tags: firewall, port, telnet, windows-firewall

I can't use command **telnet localhost**, always get this error :

> **Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port
>   23: Connect failed**

Even I have all ports allow connection in inbound and outbound rules in Windows firewall.

My OS : Windows 7

Comment: Do you actually have a `telnetd` running? It's not at all normal for Windows.

Comment: Hi geekosaur, do you mean enable telnet client in windows features ? If it is, yes I did.

Comment: You need the telnet *server*; you have the client.

Comment: you should run netstat -aon see if the server is listening it probably isn't. listening on port 23

Comment: Solved ! I have to enter 192.168.1.1 instead of "localhost"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 does not come with a **`telnet server`** installed by default. Here is how to install it:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770501(WS.10).aspx#bkmk_installVista